# how I can show interstitial ads with a random presentation

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

hello I want to show interstitial ads with a random click on button example if I click on wallpaper 3 times the interstitial ads is showing up I want to add a function to showing Interstitial randomly after click, between 3 to 10 click

this my code :

```
if (Config.Counter == 2){
Config.Counter = 0;
new InterstitialAdMobModel(activity);
}else{
Config.Counter ++;
}
```

Comment: ``I want to set ads to showing up between 3 to 10 click`` - I don't get this, can you explain please ?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @SchiduLuca sure example if I click on wallpaper 3 times the interstitial ads is showing up I want to add a function to showing Interstitial randomly after click, between 3 to 10 click

Comment: @csmckelvey  if I click on wallpaper 3 times the interstitial ads is showing up I want to add a function to showing Interstitial randomly after click, between 3 to 10 click. can you help me to edit it

Comment: Just generate a random number between 3 and 10 (you can google for how to do it). Then use that variable in your condition instead of a hard coded 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if (Config.Counter >= random ){

                    Random rand = new Random();
                    random = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);
                    new  InterstitialAdMobModel(activity);
                    Config.Counter = 0;
                }else{
                    Config.Counter ++;

                }
```